# Discovering User Location

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I'm looking for a way (PHP or some variation of Javascript) to discover a users rough location (within 500 kilometres/300 miles).  I have done plenty of Google searches and I think I've all but exhausted any current means I am aware of.

IP Address Databases, like MaxMind etc all put my location at Brisbane, QLD, Australia, when in actual fact my location is Townsville, QLD, Australia.  This is because of the way my ISP (Australia's largest) operates.  I'd prefer not to use HTML5's GeoLocation if possible.  A splash page on the website with the 2 locations only I feel will deter people from the website.

My client has two locations, each with separate sections within the website, these locations are Townsville & Brisbane.  I don't need a users address, suburb, or even City, only something that will allow them to default to either location.

Comment: GeoIP databases are simply not that fine-grained. They're only as good as the information that the ISPs supply.

Comment: Not a criticism of your plans, but personally I absolutely *HATE* it when a website 'discovers' my location, and many times it's wrong due to VPN use or just bad programming, and causes alot of inconvenience. I prefer to get a location based on the website I visited, and then have an option to switch. But maybe that's just me!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the most technical solution, but a surefire way to determine location is to ask the user about her preferred location upon her first visit and then to set a permanent cookie for future visits. This is the approach I have seen most often from my experience with businesses which have multiple locations. I have found it to be quite common. It also prevents user frustration as they travel.

As I'm sure you know, setting a cookie is very easy in either PHP or JavaScript.

As you stated, your other options are to use the user's IP or ask for geolocation approval.